# Flash SWF taking up too much RAM - crashing unexpectedly?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash, ram

I have created a game in Adobe Flash CS6 which uses a lot of video files. As a result it seems that when I try and publish the game I manage to get to the 4th question and the game just crashes. I have looked into the processes on my system and whilst playing the .swf file my RAM increases to 3GB! Surely this isn't right? Is there a possible way of making it so the file doesn't take up so much RAM so it can work all the way through?

I hope somebody can help me! Thanks

Comment: Videos are streamed in chunks and should only require a little RAM when playing (i.e., not the entire video's worth). Make sure it doesn't load multiple instances of video players (for example in an out-of-control loop) or that it doesn't eat up a lot of RAM in some other part of the code that isn't directly connected to the videos.

Answer (score 0):

The videos, are they local? Such as, are they imported to flash, or does flash use the url command to retrieve the video?

are the videos optimized?

Comment: The videos are not imported into flash, it basically calls the video from whichever drive it is in, eg (F:/...) I'm pretty sure they're not optimised, they havent really been edited in any way. they are just .mp4 files. thanks